# Make supervisord wait for mounting

Tags: mount, supervisord

How can I make a task wait till mounting point is ready in supervisord?

systemd has this:

```
After=big.mount
```

I have a USB HDD and it takes ages to startup, there is no point starting tasks early that depend on it.

doc doesn't seem to mention it http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

I guess stopping the task when mounting is gone is asking for to much, but after failure at least it wouldn't start up again.

Comment: I don't think supervisord has an option for that. You could write a wrapper script that waits until the mount point is populated.

Comment: Another option could be an [udev rule](https://askubuntu.com/a/25091/17547) that starts the service when the disk is mounted. Stopping the service could be possible that way as well.